# embedding UICollectionView inside another CollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to embed whole horizontally scrolling `collectionView` inside another vertically scrolling main `UICollectionViewController` cell like so

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
let collection = HourlyCollectionController(collectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
// HourlyCollection.colllectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
cell.addSubview(collection.view)
collection.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collection.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
collection.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
collection.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
collection.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
return cell
```

Everything appears to be looking fine until I press on the cell or try to scroll it then my collectionView just disappears and I'm left with a blank cell, anyone could suggest why?

Comment: why do you need this complexity? having a single collectionViewCell with horizontal and vertical scrolling should work. just wanted to ask what's a `collection.view`? isn't a collectionView already a view itself, so you just need to do a cell.contentView.addSubview(collection). one more you are doing a cell.AddSubView, use contentView instead

Comment: There isn't much complexity here maybe I just phrased the question in a way difficult to understand, but  I do `collection.view` since `collection` is of type `UICollectionViewController`. Another weird thing is If I seem to use a basic `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and just copy and paste the code inside the cell  `init(frame:)` it seems to be working fine.